# Select most popular and active values from an PostgresQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, scripting

I have a database structure, that looks like this:

[image]

The query i want to create is one, that selects the most popular active classes.
Active is defined by having a end date in the future (still active), 
and most popular is defined by having most classmembers.

So far i have this query:

```sql
CREATE VIEW popularclasses AS
SELECT COUNT(studentid) AS amount
FROM classes 
JOIN classmembers ON classes.classid = classmembers.classid
WHERE ends > NOW();
```

I try to create a view, where i count all the student id's and join on the other table, then  i try to make a WHERE clause , to mark only the active ones.

My issue is that i want to get the amount of students out of each class, and then do something like

```sql
... sort desc LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is a group by operator.

You want to regroup the students when they are in the same class, and then count the number of students in each class.

```
CREATE VIEW popularclasses AS
SELECT
  classes.classid,
  COUNT(*) AS amount
FROM
  classes
JOIN classmembers ON classes.classid = classmembers.classid
GROUP BY
  classes.classid
ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 10;
```

(I have not tried this code)

Comment: It worked fine tank you. By any means, do you know if the where condition would also work?

Comment: Oh I forgot about this part. I don't see why it wouldn't work, as long as it's not in the "groupped" table, you can use it the same as before. Columns in the aggregated table should be used with an aggregation function (count, sum, max, min...).